# keeping tab state when switching tabs in angular

Tags: angularjs, tabs, state, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an angular application with angular-ui-bootstrap that has dynamic tabs (with different views in them).
It seems that when you select a tab, the previously selected tab contents gets thrown away and reloaded when I go back.
I'm looking for a way to save the state of the contents of the tab.

I found this example that shows what I want but because they are storing the state of the tab in the parent viewmodel and my application has dynamic tabs this is not a workable solution 
http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/08/14/dynamic-tabs-with-angularjs-and-ui-bootstrap.aspx

here they suggest that not using tabs, but just showing/hiding is a way:
[angular ui-router maintaining state between tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20282981/angular-ui-router-maintaining-state-between-tabs)

but is it the only way / best way?

Comment: Are you wanting to save the model bindings or the DOM of the closed tabs?

Comment: both.. the most impressive solution I found so far was sticky states from ui-router-extras: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/sticky/index.html#/

Answer (score 1):

Dont use this. Make your own tabs and load their contents under them in DOM. Show only one at time. You should change the angular hidden way too because it should not work as you expect on chrome. Default is display: none or hidden (dont remenber) and chrome remove it form perf probably.

You can put your div out of the screen or somethings, play with positions and opacity....

Comment: It's not css issue but Angular directive one. I don't know angular ui tabs but from what he post it look like DOM is removed and compile again when you switch tabs.